# How to change data property on destroyed v-dialog component?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have dialog component with form inside. I want to remove `errorMessage` data property when the dialog closes. I can't do this, because function `destroyed()` doesn't work for it, it just added class `display:none`.

How can I remove this error message, when I close the dialog modal?

```
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="modal" max-width="800px">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-btn
        v-on="on"
        :disabled="disabled">
        open dialog
      </v-btn>
    </template>
    <v-card>
            <v-card-text>
              <v-alert class="mb-4" :value="true" v-if='errorMessage' type="error">{{errorMessage}}</v-alert>
            </v-card-text>
              <v-btn
                @click="downloadParameters"
                :loading="loading"
                class="success">
                Create excel
              </v-btn>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    disabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
  },
  data () {
    return {
      modal: false,
      loading: false,
      errorMessage: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onCancel () {
      this.modal = false;
    },
    downloadParameters:async function(){
      const requestBody = {
        startDate: this.date,
        endDate: this.dateEnd
      };
      this.loading = false;
      this.errorMessage = null;
      try {
        this.loading = false;
        const res = await this.$store.dispatch(url,requestBody);
      } catch (e) {
        this.loading = false;
        this.errorMessage = 'Error message';
      }
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.errorMessage = '';
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Vue watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) for this

```
watch: {
  model(newVal) {
    if (!newVal) {
      this.errorMessage = null
    }
  }
}
```